# Boolean AND logic in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 AIF QueryCriteria

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa892862.aspx):

> The system uses Boolean OR logic to connect all the  tags.

Does this mean that it is entirely impossible to construct a QueryCriteria which performs a boolean AND operation between multiple CriteriaElements?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to get what you want by using a 'dirty trick' with queries.
There is a way to put custom expressions in query ranges by using the DataArea field or the RecId field and putting in your expression.

Example:

```
query = new Query();
dsInventTable = query.addDataSource(tableNum(InventTable));

// Add our range
queryBuildRange = dsInventTable.addRange(fieldNum(InventTable, DataAreaId));

queryBuildRange.value(strFmt('((%1 == %2) || ((%1 == %3) && (%4 == "%5")))',
    fieldStr(InventTable, ItemType),
    any2int(ItemType::Service),
    any2int(ItemType::Item),
    fieldStr(InventTable, ProjCategoryId),
    queryValue("Spares")));
```

See the following link for more information : [Expressions in query ranges](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Expressions_in_query_ranges)

Comment: In adition to this syntax, you can use the queryValue() function to cast any variable of any type to a valid string usable on query ranges.